# QToolBar Border setStyleSheet()

Tags: c++, qt

I have a number of QToolBar's in Qt::TopToolBarArea of my QMainWindow. I want to remove the left and right borders from the ones which are not on the edges. However, when  try the following code, it ends up erasing ALL of the borders on the QToolBar:

toolBar2->setStyleSheet("QToolBar { border-left-style: none; border-right-style: none; }");

I want this to appear as one continuous tool bar, with no borders between them. What is the proper way to achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're right, styling one or more of the borders (including removing it) ends up removing the rest. This is because style sheets and Qt Styles don't mix very well, and the Qt Style usually loses.

What you can do is bring back the borders you do want to see. This example specifies how the top and bottom borders should appear, which in turn removes the left and right boders:

```
toolBar2->setStyleSheet("QToolBar {border-bottom: 2px solid black; border-top: 2px solid black;}");
```

Comment: Only problem with this is that those thick black borders do not appear as the default on my machine. Also, seems to be missing the gradient background.

Comment: @DragonDrop I made the borders black just to be certain you could see them. In practice, you should make them whatever color you want, or whatever color is the default border color on your machine. I believe you can use QPalette to find that out at runtime. Also, you can easily style the background of QToolBar with the "background" style sheet property.

Comment: I learned the hard way that the order of thickness, style, and color values in the border property, which is not important in a normal webpage, is  very important for a Qt widget.  @Anthony's answer (e.g., `{border-top: 2px solid black;}` works, and the top border appears.  However, I was in the habit of putting the thickness last, so when I typed `{border-top: solid black 2px;}`, the top border did not appear.  Test environment: Qt 4.7.4 for Windows.